# reading sequential data store into column

Tags: java

I have a file that contains five rows with sequential data.i want to  store character from that file into a coloumn. if i put some fix sized characters into a first row four column then remaining characters will also put into a second row four column respectively.please help me to solve out problem

My file is :-

```
Authorization is the assurance that the user is allowed to access only those resources that he is authorized to use. 
For example, in a corporate application, there are some parts of an application where only admin have access and to 
some parts all the employees have access. These access rules are determined by the access rights given to each user 
of the system. At the authorization level, spring targets three main areas: authorizing web request, authorizing 
whether methods can be invoked and authorizing access to individual domain object instances.
```

My code is

```
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


       public class LoadData {
    private static String line;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String col1,col2,col3,col4, col;
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            FileReader in = new FileReader("D:\\WebsiteDemo\\ReadingFileDemo\\data.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line.trim();
                str.add(line);
                System.out.println(str);
                System.out.println(line);

                int len = line.length();
                for(int i=0;i< len;i++)
                {
                    col1=line.substring(0,5);
                    col2=line.substring(5, 7);
                    col3=line.substring(7, 10);
                    col4=line.substring(10,20);
                    //line=line.substring(21, line.length());

                    System.out.println("col1...."+col1);
                    System.out.println("col2>>>...."+col2);
                    System.out.println("col3...."+col3);
                    System.out.println("col4...."+col4);
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

output

[Authorization is the assurance that the user is allowed to access only those resources that he is authorized to use. ]
Authorization is the assurance that the user is allowed to access only those resources that he is authorized to use.

```
col1....Autho
col2>>>....ri
col3....zat
col4....ion is the
col1....Autho
col2>>>....ri
col3....zat
col4....ion is the
col1....Autho
col2>>>....ri
col3....zat
col4....ion is the
col1....Autho
col2>>>....ri
col3....zat
col4....ion is the
col1....Autho
col2>>>....ri
col3....zat
col4....ion is the......so on until end of line
```

Comment: please help mi to solve out my problem

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: when i going to execute code it will print  0-5 character in 1st col,5-7 in 2nd col ,7-10 in third col, and 10-20 in last column.but it skips remaining line it repeatedly print same thing until end of line.what can i do so that remaining character will put into respective column

Comment: In your for loop, you need to use dynamic indexes to get the substring. You are assigning the same substrings to your col1,col2... variables.

Comment: can you please provide code  for this

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic indexing to get the substrings. As follows:

```
    int start = 0 ;
    while(start < len)
    {
        col1=line.substring(start,start+5);
        col2=line.substring(start+5, start+7);
        col3=line.substring(start+7, start+10);
        col4=line.substring(start+10,start+20);

        //line=line.substring(21, line.length());

        System.out.println("col1...."+col1);
        System.out.println("col2>>>...."+col2);
        System.out.println("col3...."+col3);
        System.out.println("col4...."+col4);
        start += 20 ;
    }
```

You may have to check the substring parameters with the length of the string.

Comment: it gives java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 120 exception at line                                                                    col4=line.substring(start+10,start+20);

Comment: **You may have to check the substring parameters with the length of the string**

Comment: I m not getting what r u saying